# Getting Error in JSON from Web API values

Tags: c#, json, winforms

i want to get the string values from a dota web api format is JSON but failed to do so, the url is displaying the values but it's not formatted with what i want, i need to know what's wrong with my code?

The Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

JSON File

```
{
    "result": 
    {
        "games":[
        {
            "players":[
            {
                "account_id": 7054833,
                "name": "Директор",
                "hero_id": 62,
                "team": 0
            },
            {
                "account_id": 228767798,
                "name": "Ya.хз",
                "hero_id": 93,
                "team": 1
            }],
            "radiant_team":
            {
                "team_name": "InG.gaming",
                "team_id": 2374581,
                "team_logo": 534020692608135988,
                "complete": false
            },
            "dire_team":
            {
                "team_name": "Night_Players",
                "team_id": 2090745,
                "team_logo": 36365589572601277,
                "complete": false
            },   
            "lobby_id": 24047453607354324,
            "match_id": 1524116173,
            "spectators": 146,
            "league_id": 2091,
            "stream_delay_s": 120,
            "radiant_series_wins": 0,
            "dire_series_wins": 0,
            "series_type": 0,
            "league_tier": 1,
            "scoreboard":
            {
                "duration": 1233.2655029296875,
                "roshan_respawn_timer": 0,
                "radiant": 
                {
                    "score": 11,
                    "tower_state": 1574,
                    "barracks_state": 63,
                    "picks":[
                    {
                        "hero_id": 26
                    },
                    {
                        "hero_id": 62
                    }],
                    "bans":[
                    {
                        "hero_id": 85
                    },
                    {
                        "hero_id": 30
                    }],
                    "players":[
                    {
                        "player_slot": 1,
                        "account_id": 166715230,
                        "hero_id": 21,
                        "kills": 5,
                        "death": 4,
                        "assists": 0,
                        "last_hits": 60,
                        "denies": 5,
                        "gold": 10,
                        "level": 11,
                        "gold_per_min": 355,
                        "xp_per_min": 337,
                        "ultimate_state": 3,
                        "ultimate_cooldown": 0,
                        "item0": 77,
                        "item1": 50,
                        "item2": 164,
                        "item3": 166,
                        "item4": 46,
                        "item5": 0,
                        "respawn_timer": 18,
                        "position_x": -4199.75,
                        "position_y": -6644.25732421875,
                        "net_worth": 6520
                    },
                    {
                         "player_slot": 2,
                         "account_id": 92826288,
                         "hero_id": 54,
                         "kills": 0,
                         "death": 3,
                         "assists": 4,
                         "last_hits": 87,
                         "denies": 17,
                         "gold": 791,
                         "level": 11,
                         "gold_per_min": 359,
                         "xp_per_min": 370,
                         "ultimate_state": 3,
                         "ultimate_cooldown": 0,
                         "item0": 50,
                         "item1": 151,
                         "item2": 7,
                         "item3": 36,
                         "item4": 182,
                         "item5": 0,
                         "respawn_timer": 0,
                         "position_x": -1377.1424560546875,
                         "position_y": -6401.39501953125,
                         "net_worth": 7066
                     }],
```

C# Code

```
public partial class LiveLeagues
{
    public class BasePlayer
    {
        [JsonProperty("account_id")]
        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hero_id")]
        public int HeroId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("team")]
        public int Team { get; set; }
    }
}

public class ViewLiveLeaguePlayers
    {
        public List<LiveLeagues.BasePlayer> Players { get; set; }
    }
```

Main Form

```
       private async void FetchLiveLeagueGames()
       {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetLiveLeagueGames/v1/?key=************");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewLiveLeaguePlayers data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewLiveLeaguePlayers>(responseBody);
                foreach (var players in data.Players)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(players.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you see on what line the exception comes up?

Comment: its pointed on Program.cs "Application.Run(new frmMain());"

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace!

Comment: As far as I can see you want to parse subtree that starts not from the top. You want to parse players that are within result/games. I suggest to include extra Result class with Games property

Comment: actually i have a     

public partial class LiveLeagues
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public LiveGames Result { get; set; }
    }

what do i need to do?

Comment: Why not deserializing this way LiveLeagues data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveLeagues>(responseBody); ?

Comment: do i need to make my BasePlayer class abstract then inherit the values from result class?

Comment: sorry im new to json, im kinda confused

Comment: No you should not. All you need to do is to reproduce JSON structure in NET so that deserialization can be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your JSON structure you need extra layer in NET code

```
public class ResponseData
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public LiveLeagues Result{ get; set; }
}
public class LiveLeagues
{
    [JsonProperty("games")]
    public List<ViewLiveLeaguePlayers> Games{ get; set; }
}
```

This case you can write

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(responseBody);
foreach (var game in data.Result.Games)
{
  foreach (var players in game.Players)
  {
    listView1.Items.Add(players.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i will try this later and give feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: I forgot one more layer here - please check the updated answer. You need something containing result as well

Comment: it works bro! thank you very much, i got the list of players :)